# AVR XMEGA USART Simulation

Tags: c++, avr, atmel, usart, atmelstudio

Using the test code below, I'm trying to send data over the `USART` of an `xmega128a3u` using the `simulator` in `Atmel Studio.` Watching the I/O view the Data register is never set even though I'm setting it. Is there something wrong with my code or the simulator or what?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define bscale 0
#define bsel 0x0003 //250kbps
#define packetFormat (USART_SBMODE_bm | USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc | USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc)


uint8_t n;

int main(void)
{
    //ALLOW PORTB AND PORTF TO BE WRITTEN TO! TURNS OFF JTAG
    CCP = 0xD8; //Allow Protected IO changing
    MCU_MCUCR = 0x1;

    //CRYSTAL SETUP
    OSC_XOSCCTRL = OSC_FRQRANGE_12TO16_gc | OSC_XOSCSEL_XTAL_16KCLK_gc; // 16Mhz Crystal
    OSC_CTRL |= OSC_XOSCEN_bm;
    while(!(OSC_STATUS & OSC_XOSCRDY_bm)); //Wait for crystal to stabilize.
    CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
    CLK_CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_XOSC_gc;
    //END CRYSTAL SETUP


    cli();


    //Enable Interrupts
    USARTF0.CTRLA = USART_TXCINTLVL_LO_gc | USART_DREINTLVL_LO_gc;

    //Enable transmitter
    USARTF0.CTRLB = USART_TXEN_bm;

    PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_LOLVLEX_bm;

    //Set baud
    USARTF0.BAUDCTRLB = bscale;
    USARTF0.BAUDCTRLA = bsel;

    //Set packet format
    USARTF0.CTRLC = packetFormat;

    sei();

    while (1) 
    {
        if(n < 255) {
            USARTF0.DATA  = n;

        } else {
            n = 0;  
        }
    }
}

ISR(USARTF0_TXC_vect) {
    n++;
}

ISR(USARTF0_DRE_vect) {
    n++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably should make `n` volatile in this case as there's a very good chance that the compiler doesn't see the ISR code and hence optimizes out the branch `if(n < 255)` because `n` is not changed in that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are other registers being updated, just not DATA? If not, make sure you've enabled the clock to the USART. Many micros also use one DATA register for reads and writes. Thus attempting to read the DATA register after writing (I.e., the debug view is doing a read) won't return anything unless data has been received. Thus you'd likely see the same behavior even if executing on hardware.

That said, in my experience the simulator in Atmel Studio isn't very good at simulating interrupts or peripheral operation.

**Edit to include informatino from comments below:**
Since you can't read back something you just wrote to the DATA register, checking the DREIF flag in the STATUS register right after you write the data will confirm whether or not the data is being transmitted.

Comment: Yeah, the other registers are updating. I added a screenshot.

Comment: OK. I looked up the manual for the xmega128A3U and the DATA register for the USART does double duty: when you write to it, it will copy that character to its' transmit shift register and when you read it will read out received data.  Thus whenever you write data to the register for transmission, you won't be able read it back out.

Try checking DREIF flag in the USART STATUS register right after you write to DATA. That should provide indication if the data is being sent or not, though I'm not sure how well the simulator would show this.

Comment: Yup, the DREIF flag gets set. I tried the code out on an actual chip and everything worked. So, the simulator isn't capable of displaying the data register value.

Comment: Good to know it's just the simulator. If that answers your question I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer above as accepted.